# how to find close points between two values in animation nodes

Tags: animation-nodes, splines

I'm trying to make some splines and I found  "find close points" node but the problem  is it has just one value : max distance , but how can I make edges between two values min and max? or in general how to get some objects from a list based on their properties?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create mask for filtering edges by finding intersection of Min and Max distances.
[image]

Comment: thank you so much